How can I mock prompt-sync module using jest
I have this method promptPlayer in the class Player which job is to return to the player the index of an empty slot. But inside the method I am running prompt from the prompt-sync module of JS. Cant seem to mock this properly I have searched everywhere but cant find a correct guide.
player.js
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();

class Player {
    constructor(name, mark) {
        this.name = name
        this.mark = mark
    }

    validOption(emptySlots, row, col) {
        // if empty slot return false its valid option
        // if occopied slot return false its invalid option
        if (typeof(row) !== "number" || typeof(col) !== "number") {
            return false;
        }

        row = parseInt(row);
        col = parseInt(col);
        if (row >= 3 || col >= 3) {
            return false;
        }


        if (emptySlots[row][col] === ".") {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    promptPlayer(emptySlots) {
        // console.log("Choose an empty slot.");

        let row = prompt("Enter the row number (0, 1, or 2): ");
        let col = prompt("Enter the column number (0, 1, or 2): ");

        console.log("ROW IS", row); // logs undefiend in the test case
        console.log("COL IS", col); // logs undefiend in the test case


        const isValid = this.validOption(emptySlots, row, col);

        if (!isValid) {
            console.log("Invalid selection please select the expected values.");
            console.log();
            return this.promptPlayer(emptySlots);
        } else {
            return {
                row: parseInt(row),
                col: parseInt(col),
                mark: this.mark
            }
        }
    }


The variables row and col logs as undefined on the test case.
TEST.
player.test.js

const each = require("jest-each").default;
const { Player } = require("../player");
// Mock the prompt-sync module
jest.mock("prompt-sync", () => () => jest.fn());


let player;
let emptySlots;

describe("Player Class", () => {


    beforeEach(() => {
        player = new Player("Player 1", "X");
        emptySlots = [
            ["X", ".", "."],
            ["O", ".", "."],
            [".", ".", "."]
        ];
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks(); // Clear mock calls between tests
    })


    it("promptPlayer returns { row, col, mark }", () => {

        // Arrange
        const mockPrompt = require("prompt-sync")();

        // Act
        // Mock the input values for row and column
        mockPrompt.mockReturnValueOnce("0").mockReturnValueOnce("2");
        const result = player.promptPlayer(emptySlots);

        // Log to verify . does n
        console.log("Result:", result);

        // Assign
        expect(result).toEqual({
            row: 0,
            col: 2,
            mark: "X"
        });
    })

})





As I have tried the testing the mocking for prompt the variable I am storing the prompt like row and col are still undefined even when I have done mock on them. Please kindly let me know where I am going wrong here.
The test goes into infinite loop in the end it breaks off with row and col where I console.log them that they are undefined

Your arrange step is incorrect.
const mockPrompt = require("prompt-sync")();

The above statement will give you a different prompt function, it's not the same prompt function used in the player.promptPlayer() method.
We should mock the create function and prompt function. Then, we can get the mock prompt function via mockFn.mock.results.
e.g.
player.js:
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

class Player {
  constructor(name, mark) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mark = mark;
  }

  validOption(emptySlots, row, col) {
    //...
  }

  promptPlayer(emptySlots) {
    let row = prompt('Enter the row number (0, 1, or 2): ');
    let col = prompt('Enter the column number (0, 1, or 2): ');

    console.log('ROW IS', row);
    console.log('COL IS', col);
  }
}

module.exports = { Player };

player.test.js:
const { Player } = require('./player');
const promptSync = require('prompt-sync');

jest.mock('prompt-sync', () => jest.fn(() => jest.fn()));

let player;
let emptySlots;

describe('Player Class', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    player = new Player('Player 1', 'X');
    emptySlots = [
      ['X', '.', '.'],
      ['O', '.', '.'],
      ['.', '.', '.'],
    ];
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks(); // Clear mock calls between tests
  });

  it('promptPlayer returns { row, col, mark }', () => {
    // Arrange

    const mockPrompt = promptSync.mock.results[0].value;

    // Act
    // Mock the input values for row and column
    mockPrompt.mockReturnValueOnce('0').mockReturnValueOnce('2');
    player.promptPlayer(emptySlots);

    // Assert
  });
});

Test result:

  console.log
    ROW IS 0

      at Player.log [as promptPlayer] (stackoverflow/78770377/player.js:17:13)

  console.log
    COL IS 2

      at Player.log [as promptPlayer] (stackoverflow/78770377/player.js:18:13)

 PASS  stackoverflow/78770377/player.test.js
  Player Class
    √ promptPlayer returns { row, col, mark } (15 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.781 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

